# Python - Can't change value of item inside a class

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python, and don't understand why I can't do this.
When I try to change the values in Packet.ItemData from the parent object, it doesn't work. See the "Doesn't work" comments in the code.

```
import json
from copy import deepcopy


class Event():
    __slots__= 'itemName'

    def __init__(self, itemName):
        self.itemName = itemName


    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['itemName'] = str(self.itemName)               
        return json.dumps(obj)

    def decode(self, json_Str):
        obj = json.loads(json_Str)
        self.itemName = obj['itemName']        



class Packet():
    __slots__= 'pID', 'itemData' 

    def __init__(self, pID, itemData):
        self.pID = pID
        self.itemData = itemData

    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['pID'] = int(self.pID)
        obj['itemData'] = str(self.itemData.encode())

        return json.dumps(obj)

    def decode(self, json_Str):
        obj = json.loads(json_Str)
        self.pID = obj['pID']
        self.itemData = Event(0,'')


defaultEvent = Event('Dflt')
defaultPacket = Packet(1, defaultEvent)



event2 = Event('NoName')
print 'event : ', event2.encode()
packet3 = deepcopy(defaultPacket)
packet3.ItemData = event2; #direct assign doesn't work
packet3.ItemData = deepcopy(event2); #deep copy doesn't work
packet3.ItemData.itemName = 'Hello' #event this doesn't work
print 'packet : ', packet3.encode()
```

I wanted to wrap up the data so I get exactly what I am expecting when encoding and decoding from JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What FJ pointed out is indeed correct...the name of the attribute is `itemData` not `ItemData`.

Being new to Python you may have expected that typo to throw an error...something like 'Packet has no attribute ItemData', but this does not happen. Python classes by default store attributes in a dictionary, so assigning to one that did not exist previously is just like adding a new mapping to the dictionary.

Curiously, your code in a roundabout way highlights an exception to this...and that has to do with the descriptor `__slots__`. `__slots__` changes the class to no longer store attributes in a dynamic dictionary, but in a static structure instead. See [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots) for more info.

Normally, when `__slots__` is defined you can not assign to an attribute that wasn't specified in `__slots__`. So you may ask....since you defined `__slots__` for your classes why didn't you get an `AttributeError`? The answer is `__slots__` will only work for 'new-style classes' See [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) to learn about the distinction between old and new-style classes.

Had you defined `Packet` to inherit from the base class `object` like `class Packet(object):` instead of just `class Packet()` it would have made it a new-style class and you would have indeed gotten an `AttributeError` when you tried to assign to `ItemData`

Comment: Thanks, I hate chase sensitive, so use to pascal.  I was trying to use the slots to prevent extra data from being in there.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute name is `itemData`, not `ItemData`.  If you change all of the `packet3.ItemData` references to `packet3.itemData` this should work fine.